# Functionality for lock on sub-document level in mongo

Tags: mongodb

For locking on document level we do have findAndModify which locks the document even if parallel calls are received and only releases the lock until the data is updated so that the next task in queue will read only the updated document.
But is there anything for locking a sub-document or specific key in a document?
For my question let’s take an example of mongo data for a single document:

```
{
    "reservedQuantity": 100,
    "sku": "ABCD",
    "inStock": 200,
    "shipReserved": 400
}
```

Let’s say there is a high traffic with parallel calls to update reservedQuantity for sku ABCD. Is there any function which enables to lock only the key reservedQuantity for this document until it is updated and meanwhile allows other calls to read/write data in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

`findAndModify` doesn't lock the documents in a manner that prevents any other updates. It makes sure that documents match your query before updating them.
see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#AtomicOperations-FindandModify%28orRemove%29)

---

Here is an example :

Let say that this is our DB

```
[{
    "reservedQuantity": 100,
    "sku": "ABCD",
    "inStock": 200,
    "shipReserved": 400
}]
```

In a task, we want to perform a **query A**, with this kind of `findAndModify`

```
(
{
    "reservedQuantity": 100,
    "sku": "ABCD",
    "inStock": 200,
    "shipReserved": 400
},
{
   "$set": {"sku": "EFGH"}
}
)
```

If documents exactly match our document it will update the `sku` field.

We also have **query B**, which is the query happening "simultaneously"
This query wants to change `inStock` to 300.

If query A is performed before query B:

- query A is updatding `sku` to "EFGH"
- query B is updatding `inStock` to 300.

If query B is performed before query A:

- query B is updatding `inStock` to 300.
- query A will not further match any document and will not change `sku`

`findAndModify` won't prevent parallel calls do update your document.
But it makes sure that the documents you are updating are in the desired state.